# $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ Yang-Mills symmetry breaking to $\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}$

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, symmetry-breaking

I want to break $\operatorname{SU}(n)\to\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}$ using a vev of an adjoint scalar and find the charges of the now massive vectors under $\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}$, but I don't know how to do this.

For context, I want to do this since I must convince myself that in M-theory propagating on a spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{1,6}\times S_{A_{n-1}}$ where $S_{A_{n-1}}$ is a resolution of an $A_{n-1}$ singularity, then wrapping M2-branes on the 2-cycles of the resolution in the singular limit gives an enhanced gauge group from $\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}$ to $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ in 7 dimensions i.e I want to compare the charges of the two cases, hoping they are the same, so that I understand how the M-theory case gives an enhanced gauge group $\operatorname{SU}(n)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can see, that there is a canonical map $\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\operatorname{SU}(n)$ by mapping to the diagonal, but what is your map $\operatorname{SU}(n)\rightarrow\operatorname{U}(1)^{n-1}$?

Comment: By this notation I mean that I want to reduce the symmetry group of the Yang-Mills action from $SU(n)$ to $U(1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Have you sorted out the *n* =3 case?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't know how to explicitly work this for any n, but knowing how to do this in the n=3 case would certainly be very helpful

Comment: Your [Li Fong Li](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.1723), III.D, would suggest that just one adjoint scalar would still give you an SU(2) factor for SU(3)... It's best if you read and apply his formulas yourself to taylor them to your problem...